# Get info from child to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update the items in this react ShoppingList. I have been trying multiple setups of solving this. I don't really know how to go about it. I tried using refs and moving my items from the Items function to my ShoppingList function. I am not sure about how to pass information from the child to the parent. Here is what I am trying to do.

```js
import React, {useState, createRef} from 'react'
import AddButton from './AddButton'
import Items from './Items'

function ShoppingList(props) {

    const onSubmit = e => {
        // get items form Items
        tempItems.push(e.target[0].value)
        // set items from Items
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <AddButton onSubmit={onSubmit}  />
            <Items />
        </div>
    )
}

export default ShoppingList
```

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function Items(props) {
    const [items, setItems] = React.useState(["test"])

    function getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    function setItemss(items) {
        setItems(items)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {items.map(item => {
                return (
                    <p>{item}</p>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Items
```

Not really necessary but I will add this as well incase

```js
function AddButton(props) {

    const [input, setInput] = React.useState("")

    const onChange = e => {
        setInput(e.target.value)
    }

    const onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setInput("")
        props.onSubmit(e)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <input type="text" value={input} 
                onChange={onChange}></input>
                <input type="submit"></input>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddButton
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you find that a parent needs to access states of a child, you can always consider [lifting the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

In your case, you might want to manage `items` state in the shopping list, and ***pass the state down*** to items as a prop.

```js
import React, {useState, createRef} from 'react'
import AddButton from './AddButton'
import Items from './Items'

function ShoppingList(props) {
    const [items, setItems] = useState(["test"]);

    const onSubmit = e => {
        // We use `items.concat` here to avoid modifying 
        // the original array to ensure immutability
        setItems(items.concat(e.target[0].value));
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <AddButton onSubmit={onSubmit}  />
            <Items items={items}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ShoppingList
```

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function Items(props) {
    // We access props.items in Items, and manage the state in ShoppingList
    return (
        <div>
            {props.items.map(item => {
                return (
                    <p>{item}</p>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Items
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-cerf-ck47p?file=/src/ShoppingList.js)

Comment: I had tried that. I ran into an issue where it wouldn't update the list. Idk why but the state change wouldn't re-render the items.

Comment: Did you modify the original list?

Comment: You can try the codesandbox I added in the answer.

Comment: Scratch that. I just tried it. Apparently, when I modifying the original array it would break. I didn't know concat existed. Thank you!

Comment: Because React relies on diff to decide whether to re-render an element, modifying the original array will result in no diff. Making sure that the states are immutable is pretty important for React.

Comment: I thought when I created a tempItems it wasn't the original anymore. So I could edit it as I please then update it. I guess it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Well, tempItems is a reference to the original array, so you actually modifying the original one, whereas `concat` returns a new array.